# In R, how do I select a single value from one column, based upon a value in a second column?

Tags: r

thank you for the help.  I am attempting to write an equation that uses values selected from an .csv file.  It looks something like this, let's call it df.

```
df<-read.csv("SiteTS.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",")
df

  Site        TS
1  H4A1 -42.75209
2  H4A2 -43.75101
3  H4A3 -41.75318
4  H4C3 -46.76770
5  N1C1 -42.68940
6  N1C2 -36.95200
7  N1C3 -43.16750
8  N2A2 -38.58040
9  S4C1 -35.32000
10 S4C2 -34.52420
```

My equation requires the value in the TS column for each site.  I am attempting to create a new column called `SigmaBS` with the results of the equation using TS.

```
df["SigmaBS"]<-10^(subset(df, Site=="H4A1"/10)
```

Which is where I am running into issues, as the subset function returns all columns that correlate with the Site column = H4A1

```
subset(df, Site =="H4A1")
Site        TS
1 2411 -42.75209
```

But again, I only need the value -42.75209.

I apologize if this is a simple question, but I would very much appreciate any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: I am removing the SQL tag because this is explicitly about R.

Comment: Thank you!  It was one of the suggested tags, and the sqldf library was a potential answer to my problem so I thought it may be appropriate.

Comment: Is it always the first result from the subsetted df you're looking for?

Comment: No, the same equation will have to be used for each site.  So:

'df["SigmaBS"]<-10^(subset(df, Site=="H4A1"/10)
df["SigmaBS"]<-10^(subset(df, Site=="H4A2"/10)
df["SigmaBS"]<-10^(subset(df, Site=="H4A3"/10)'

And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using the subset function, it has a `select` argument:

```
subset(df, Site=="H4A1", select="TS")
```

A better option is to use `[]` notation:

```
df[df$Site=="H4A1", "TS"]
```

Or the `$` operator:

```
subset(df, Site=="H4A1")$TS
```

Comment: The select argument was something I was unaware of... I must have missed it or forgotten it in my delving into the issue, thank you.

Comment: Apologies again, but what if I were to require the selection of multiple rows.  In this example I am selecting for TS values only, but if I wanted to select additional column values that are in the same row as H4A1 could I do the following:  df[df$Site=="H4A1", "TS, TS2, TS3"] ?

Comment: Close, the column names need to be a character vector: `df[df$Site=="H4A1", c("TS", "TS2", "TS3")]`

Comment: Thank you, this filled another part of the data organization that I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple command:

```
df$SigmaBS <- 10 ^ (df$TS / 10)
```

Comment: Simple and effective, this works for the particular problem I have.  Thank you!

Comment: Apologies, I am still getting used to the site.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to create a new column called `SigmaBS` where the values in each row are `10^(value of TS) / 10`

If so, this code should work:

```
SigmaBS <- sapply(df$TS, function(x) 10^(x/10))
df$SigmaBS <- SigmaBS
```